# How do I make my own alias override a module's alias?

Tags: powershell, alias

I have an alias for `touch` created in my `$profile`, however I also use PSCX seems to have it's own `touch`. When I run `touch` the PSCX one runs:

```
$ which touch
Pscx\Set-FileTime
```

How do I make PowerShell prefer my alias over the modules alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `$PROFILE`:

- *First*, explicitly import the `PSCX` module - at that point, that module's `touch` alias is imported and would replace any existing definition: `Import-Module PSCX`

  - Note: Add `Import-Module PSCX` even if it currently *isn't* in your `$PROFILE`; typically, the module is [*auto-loaded*, *on demand*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules#module-auto-loading), by virtue of being located in one of the directories listed in the `$env:PSModulePath` environment variable.
    It is that on-demand importing - whose timing is unpredictable (whenever you first happen to call a command from the module) - that prevents reliable alias replacement; forcing import of the module in your `$PROFILE` *before* you define your version of the alias solves that problem.
- *Then* redefine the alias as needed; e.g.: `Set-Alias touch touch.exe`

  - *Caveat*: If someone *forcefully re-imports* the  module later with `Import-Module -Force PSCX`, your alias will again be replaced.

Note: It's not necessary for the specific alias in question, but in order to replace aliases that are defined with `-Option AllScope` (true for built-in aliases such as `dir` and `select`), you're faced with two suboptimal choices:

- Either: *Redefine* it with `-Option AllScope`, which, however, means that *all* scopes will see the new definition; e.g., `Set-Alias -Option AllScope touch touch.exe`.
- Or: *Remove* the original alias first - e.g., `Remove-Item alias:touch` (PSv6+: `Remove-Alias touch`) - and then *define* it as needed, which, however, means that other scopes will no longer see the original definition.

Comment: just because you can do something does not make it a good idea.  personally, i'd just call my alias something else and avoid all the above.  OP has good info to make informed decision for his scenario.

Comment: @mklement0 Awesome, PSCX gets loaded outside my profile but `Remove-Alias` was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @KoryGill It's very difficult to call an alias for `touch` something other than `touch` when you've been typing `touch "some file"` for twenty years.

Comment: @mikemaccana,  I fully understand.  You know how I type "driver"?  d-r-i-v-e-r-s-backspace!  #lol

Answer (score 1):

Making this an answer rather than comment so I can type more text.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/452430/how-to-override-the-default-dir-alias-in-powershell

Opinion follows:

However, depending on your usage, I would strongly recommend against using aliases in any script or module as they can be changed and may not perform the actions you want.

If you really want to use an alias, I might just avoid all this and create a non-conflicting alias that still makes sense.  Maybe `tf` or `tfile` for TouchFile.

Comment: I'm not using aliases in scripts or modules, just in my $profile for basic file management tasks.